# how to get text from <a href> in nested html elements using jericho?

Tags: java, html, parsing, jericho-html-parser

I have some html code like this

```
<div class="itm hasOverlay lastrow">
<a id="3:LE343SPABGLIANID" class="itm-link itm-drk trackingOnClick" title="League Sepatu Casual Geof S/L LO - Hitam/Biru" href="league-sepatu-casual-geof-sl-lo-hitambiru-68166.html" rel="-standard|">
</a>
<div class="itm-overlay itm-group-mainbox-with-group"></div>
</div>
```

What should I do to get text **league-sepatu-casual-geof-sl-lo-hitambiru-68166.html** in
 
  `<a href="league-sepatu-casual-geof-sl-lo-hitambiru-68166.html">`?

Comment: Sorry for the unformatted code snippet, I somehow can't get it right. I can't found code formatter..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be rather simple...

```
Source source=new Source(new StringReader(inputString));
Element aElement = source.getFirstElement(HTMLElementName.A);
String href = aElement.getAttributeValue("href");
System.out.println(href);
```

... although this makes some assumptions, of course: Namely, that the `inputString` is *only* the string that you posted (and that this part is not enclosed in other tags), and that this part only contains a single link (`a`).

(If these assumptions are not valid, one somehow has to identify this particular `div` and the correct `a` tag. For example, by searching for a `div` with the attribute `class="itm hasOverlay lastrow"` and for a `a` with the class `class="itm-link itm-drk trackingOnClick"` - in any case, one has to know more about the actual *structure* of the document from which this information should be extracted)