# Want to access attribute value

Tags: java, html, dom, html-parsing, jericho-html-parser

i need help regarding html parser i want to get the first attribute"href" value of tag  "a" please resolve my problem.I want to fetch this link from the code http://myneta.info/gujarat2012/candidate.php?candidate_id=1591, 
i am attaching the snap please see and provide some solution,
i have tried this code but not works for me -

```
String temp =  source.getElementById("main").getFirstElementByClass("grid_9").getAttributeValue("a");
```

[here is image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ftjnwlyu4cflzb0/Untitled.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
source.getElementById("main").getFirstElementByClass("grid_9").getFirstElement("a").getAttributeValue("href")
```

Comment: Actually there's almost the same answer in here [http://stackoverflow.com/q/21904177/383714](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21904177/383714)